# String Parameter not Being Marshalled Correctly to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, parameters, pinvoke

I have been provided with a DLL which is to be called by C#. The DLL contains two methods as follows

```
extern "C" {
   __declspec(dllexport) BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr);
} 

BSTR GroupInit(LPCTSTR bstrIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr) {
   CString strResult = "";
   char* sz;
   ::SetVars(bDiagErr, bProcErr);
   if (sz = ::GroupInit((char*)bstrIniFile, 1))
      strResult = sz;
   return strResult.AllocSysString();
}
```

I am attempting to call these DLLs from C# by first defining the class:

```
[DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string GroupInit(
    string strCmdFile, 
    bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, 
    bool bAllowBadProcCodes
);
```

and doing

```
this.strCommandFilePath = "C:\\MyDir\\MyCommandFile.txt";
string s = Grouper.GrouperServer.GroupInit(this.strCommandFilePath, true, true);
```

But the DLL is returning the error: 'Cannot find command file: "C"' (the first character of the path only, which I have checked in the C++ DLL). For some reason the string `this.strCommandFilePath` is not being passed into the C++ method correctly.

**What is wrong with the above call?**

---

**Edit** to address comments.

The method being called in the `if (sz = ::GroupInit((char*)bstrIniFile, 1))` statement is defined in a .c file and has the signature

```
char *GroupInit(char *szCmd, int iType)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: You've got a mess here. For some reason you are using `TCHAR`. Why are you doing that? You do need to work out what character set you are using. `TCHAR` confuses you and gives you no benefits at all. I am also very sceptical of that `(char*)` cast. Why did you do that? Also, are you 100% sure you posted the real code? Are you sure there is not a `CharSet.Unicode` in the p/invoke?

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately I have just inherited this mangled code. I know nothing about who wrote it. I am just trying to enable the underlying C code to be called (quickly) from C#. So I have taken the old C++ wrapper code [that was written as a COM library], the stuff you see inside the `GroupInit` method, and placed it inside my 'wrapper method'. I have not changed the types from what they were before. I have the old C++ wrapper code and the underlying C code so could change the types but another requirement is that this C++ code can be run on a Linux box (not worked out this part
 yet!).

Comment: That doesn't really help. You need to understand what `TCHAR` is. And why you are doing that cast.

Comment: By `TCHAR` you mean the use of `LPCTSTR`; well I believe this what you need to make interop work for different C++ compilers. I am not a C++ developer so I admit I am struggling here as to why stuff was done and when it was done. I am happy to look at changing the types but again, I need this to work with many different C++ compilers so I am not sure what is required here. In terms of the code in the `GroupInit(...)` method, I am sure it can be changed as i have no idea why the cast is being done, or even why the `if` is being used the way it is...

Comment: Note, the char cast is done because the `::GroupInit` call is calling a C method which takes a `char*`. We are looking to rewrite the entire thing, but to get through this year I must enable use from .NET. I hate this type of crap, but I have no choice.

Comment: It's the exact opposite. This only works on MS compilers! You need to know what `TCHAR` really is. Is it `char` or `wchar_t`. Can you please find out. And as for the cast, you do realise that it is illegal? For sure because you take a const buffer and pass to a non-const param. And if `TCHAR` is `wchar_t` then the cast says "treat this UTF-16 data as if it were 8 bit. Anyway, if you want to do this well I suggest that you get on top of all these issues. You cannot ignore them.

Comment: I asked Hans Passant about this when I attempted to convert these `TCHAR`s to other types and he said: _"You are making a big, big mistake. These sucky "relic types" are exactly what you need to make interop work. Using std::string is a major mistake, it has the interoperability of a brick. Only a program compiled with the exact same C++ compiler with the exact same settings and the exact same library and memory allocator can use it. Stop writing this code completely and write the C# interop to call the C functions directly."_ and ...

Comment: _"LPCTSTR has no reason for living. But it is just a typedef, the C++ compiler translates it to either const char* or const wchar_t*, types that are eminently interopable. As is BSTR. No, std::wstring is just as bad. How a COM server that only supports IDispatch got morphed into this C++ code is completely unclear to me."_ needless to say, I am confused...

Comment: Thanks again for your time @DavidHeffernan, I will look at re-writing the wrapper code. What types should I use to replace the `LPCTSTR` and was Hans wrong in the above comments? I would happily convert the wrapper C++ `GroupInit` to accept what ever is necessary...

Comment: Hans and I are completely aligned in our views. You still have to work our what TCHAR is in your program. Is it char or wchar_t? Only you can find out. Nobody else can. What character set does the C++ code use in its project options. Remember that I've no idea how you even compile the code. Perhaps you don't use VS.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you re-write. Just that you use wchar_t or char instead of TCHAR. And get a grip on const correctness. I hope this does not sound impertinent, but you do need to do some background learning. You don't really understand what you are doing and writing code in that state never ends well.

Comment: I am currently using VS2013. The `Configuration Properties` > `General` > `Project Defaults` > `Character Set` is empty/blank. The `LPCTSTR` going into my C++ `GroupInit` is being converted to `char*` because the C method `GroupInit` [same name] takes a `char*`. I am not sure where `TCHAR` is coming into this, I assume that it is resolved via the `LPCTSTR` type.

Comment: Again sorry to ask so many questions, your time is much appreciated here...

Comment: Again, you have to spend some time understanding what `TCHAR` is, and what `LPCTSTR` is. You cannot expect to make progress without that understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake to use `TCHAR` and related types here. The use case of `TCHAR` is for code that needs to compile for both Windows 9x which has no Unicode support, and Windows NT which does. Those days are long gone and `TCHAR` is obscuring the problem. What's more, the underlying code uses `char*` so it makes little sense to pretend that your wrapper code can do anything else. So switch to `char`.

On top of that you are casting away const. I guess because the function you call accepts a modifiable buffer for a parameter that it does not modify. Best solution is to fix the original library code that erroneously accepts `char*` and make it accept `const char*`. If you cannot do that then you'll need to cast away the const. But do that the C++ way with `const_cast<>`.

So, I'd have the C++ code like this:

```
BSTR GroupInit(const char* szIniFile, bool bDiagErr, bool bProcErr) {
   CString strResult = "";
   char* sz;
   ::SetVars(bDiagErr, bProcErr);
   if (sz = ::GroupInit(const_cast<char*>(szIniFile), 1))
      strResult = sz;
   return strResult.AllocSysString();
}
```

And the C# code should be:

```
[DllImport("GrouperServer.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string GroupInit(
    string strCmdFile, 
    bool bAllowBadDiagCodes, 
    bool bAllowBadProcCodes
);
```

Now, one wonders what happens to `sz`. Who is expected to deallocate that? Does it even need to be deallocated? Only you can answer those questions.